# archlinux upgrading postgresql from 11 to 13: no /opt/pgsql-11/bin/ folder

Tags: postgresql, archlinux

I am using archlinux and trying to upgrade postgresql from 11 to 13. I am following https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL

I am stuck up at

```
[postgres]$ pg_upgrade -b /opt/pgsql-11/bin -B /usr/bin -d /var/lib/postgres/olddata -D /var/lib/postgres/data
```

it says /opt/pgsql-11/bin  does not exist

How to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The postgresql-old-upgrade only supports the previous version of PostgreSQL (12 currently). It does not handle jumping multiple versions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#pg_upgrade).

> For those wishing to use pg_upgrade, a postgresql-old-upgrade package is available that will always run one major version behind the real PostgreSQL package.

You have multiple solutions :

- Install manually or make an AUR package for postgresql-12-upgrade
- Rollback your system (or at least `postgresql` and `postgresql-old-upgrade`) using the [archlinux archive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_Linux_Archive).
- Dump your old database to a SQL file and import it in the new database.

Comment: Thats the only way i think.